# uninitialized constant CreateUsers::User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing the following tutorial, to learn how to use dhtml in rails.

http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/?p=426

I reach the point where I create the migration however when I do the rake db:migrate I recieve the following error:

An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant CreateUsers::User

Don't seem to understand how I can possibly be recieving this error especially by simply following a tutorial. "/

Comment: This isn't useful to you, but if anyone else finds this question with a similar problem, it may be because you are using `config.threadsafe!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you generate the `User` model before running the migration. (`ruby script/generate model user` in the tutorial, but `rails g model User` for Rails 3)

EDIT: As Jeremy pointed out, generating the model will create a migration file for you.  The tutorial shows things in a somewhat backwards order.

Comment: For quite a while now, `generate` has created the migration along with the model when you use `generate model`, so generate the model and you get the migration file for free.

Comment: @Jeremy Weathers Yes, but the tutorial link in the OP shows the migration before generating the model.  But your point is a good one since creating a migration and then generating the model will result in 2 migration files.